# Why don't ping pong players hit the ball lightly when opponents are far away?

Tags: table-tennis

Let's say player 1 is slamming, player 2 is receiving.
I've seen professional players hit the ball so high when receiving slams (player 2), and they step back so far away from the table to receive these far away slams. Why doesn't someone like player one hit the ball so lightly as player 2 has no way to run and get back to the table to return it. I believe this is called "dropshot"

Comment: You may wish to view e.g. [8 minutes of Drop Shots in Table Tennis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckDyXVFDLtM); of course, those examples are cherry-picked to make an entertaining YouTube video but players _do_ use drop shots on occasion.

Answer (score 2):

If you hit the ball hard, when it comes back, it will likely be moving very fast. The reason is kinetic energy. When you hit the ball hard, the ball has a lot of kinetic energy. It is very difficult for your opponent to slow the ball down; if the opponent contacts the ball with a stationary paddle to return it, the ball will still be moving very fast. In order to return the ball slowly, he would need to somehow absorb the energy with his paddle, perhaps by pulling back on the paddle as it contacts the ball.

Answer (score -2):

**When Player1 is going to "Slam",** when Player2 is far away from the table, Player1 has got a lot of choice in Direction (or angle) and Player2 has to be quick in reacting and running in the right Direction. By the quick hand movement, Player2 only knows that a "Slam" is coming, but not which Direction. When Player2 reacts wrongly, Player1 might **win a Point**.

**When Player1 is going to try a "Drop Shot",** when Player2 is far away from the table, Player1 still has got a lot of choice in Direction (or angle) but that is immaterial because Player2 has to only reach the table quickly and strike back the ball. By the slow hand movement, Player2 knows that a "Drop Shot" is coming, and reaching the table is the only required reaction.
In this case, Player2 can also play a "Drop Shot" which will be closer to the net and Player1 can either risk hitting the table or hitting the net or raising the ball; All these might end with **losing a Point**.

Clearly, **"Slam" is better than "Drop Shot"**, giving a better chance of **winning a Point**.

Comment: Can you provide any references to support this answer? At the moment, it seems to be entirely speculation - and potentially bad speculation as well as a _good_ drop shot will be disguised.